# Django-Python log error on MS Azure web app

Tags: python, django, azure, stream

Good afternoon,

we have a Django web app deployed on MS Azure (App Service).

We are unable to open correctly the log stream of the Web App by using the shell (local-cmd OR MS Azure shell on dashboard,  same error).

Here the attempt to open the log stream on Azure dashboard:

```
user@Azure:~$ az webapp log tail --resource-group  OUR_RESOURCES_GROUP --name OUR_WEB_APP_NAME
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 2345, in _get_log
    .decode(std_encoding, errors='replace'), end='')  # each line of log has CRLF.
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1320, in warning
    self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'end'
```

Microsoft support tell us that this is a configuration problem, but we  checked some times the python version and the other few configurations.

May anyone help ? Thanks

Comment: Website is  based on a threading concept?

Comment: What do you mean with threading concept? The website is put up with django engine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's an issue with the Azure CLI, here is a link to Github Issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/18073